# EF Core Table-Per-Type Inheritance Key in Child Table Key Named Different than Parent

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

When I am using Table per Type inheritance and I have a derived type with a foreign key that is named differently than the parent table, how do I declare it in the model builder?

e.g.

| Parent |
| --- |
| Guid Id |
| ... |

| Child |
| --- |
| Guid ParentId |
| ... |

Class Delcaration:

```
class Parent {
   Guid Id { get; set; }
   ...
}

class Child : Parent {
  ...
}
```

and the model builder:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Child>() .... ?
```

Comment: Not possible (currently).